# yq - Assign node value with parent node key

Tags: yaml, yq

I've this YAML file:

```yaml
developers:
  bob:
    softwares:
      - yq:
          version: "1.2.3"
      - visual-studio-code:
          version: "1.2.3"
  john:
    softwares:
      - xcode:
          version: "1.2.3"
      - jq:
          version: "1.2.3"
```

and I'm trying to modify it with [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) to get this result:

```yaml
developers:
  bob:
    softwares:
      - yq:
          version: "1.2.3"
          license-owner: bob
      - visual-studio-code:
          version: "1.2.3"
          license-owner: bob
  john:
    softwares:
      - xcode:
          version: "1.2.3"
          license-owner: john
      - jq:
          version: "1.2.3"
          license-owner: john
```

Please note I want to use the 2nd level key as value for `license-owner`.

---

By using the following formula I got a result similar to what I want, however the context has been changed and only the updated segment is returned.

```bash
yq '.developers.* | .softwares[].*.license-owner = (. | key)' test.yml
```

produces:

```
softwares:
  - yq:
      version: "1.2.3"
      license-owner: bob
  - visual-studio-code:
      version: "1.2.3"
      license-owner: bob
softwares:
  - xcode:
      version: "1.2.3"
      license-owner: john
  - jq:
      version: "1.2.3"
      license-owner: john
```

Any idea how to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `|=` to update while keeping the context:

```bash
yq '.developers[] |= .softwares[][].license-owner = key' test.yaml
```

```yaml
developers:
  bob:
    softwares:
      - yq:
          version: "1.2.3"
          license-owner: bob
      - visual-studio-code:
          version: "1.2.3"
          license-owner: bob
  john:
    softwares:
      - xcode:
          version: "1.2.3"
          license-owner: john
      - jq:
          version: "1.2.3"
          license-owner: john
```

Tested with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.27.2

---

Another, imo more readable option would be to use `with_entries`, which then would work in both mikefarah/yq and kislyuk/yq (note that the latter would also require `license-owner` to be quoted as it contains "special characters"):

```bash
.developers |= with_entries(.value.softwares[][]."license-owner" = .key)
```